# Join two Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have two tables:

**Table 1: EventLog**

```
class EventLog(Base):
    """"""

    __tablename__   = 'event_logs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # Keys
    event_id        = Column(Integer)
    data            = Column(String)
    signature       = Column(String)

    # Unique constraint
    __table_args__  = (UniqueConstraint('event_id', 'signature'),)
```

**Table 2: Machine_Event_Logs**

```
class Machine_Event_Logs(Base):
    """"""

    __tablename__   = 'machine_event_logs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # Keys
    machine_id      = Column(String, ForeignKey("machines.id"))
    event_log_id    = Column(String, ForeignKey("event_logs.id"))
    event_record_id = Column(Integer)
    time_created    = Column(String)

    # Unique constraint
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('machine_id', 'event_log_id', 'event_record_id', 'time_created'),)

    # Relationships
    event_logs      = relationship("EventLog")
```

The relationship between `EventLogs` and `Machine_Event_Logs` is 1 to many.

Whereby we register a unique event log into the `EventLogs` table and then register millions of entries into `Machine_Event_Logs` for every time we encounter that event.

**Goal:** We're trying to join both table to display the entire timeline of event logs captured.

We've tried multiple combinations of the `merge()` function in Panda Dataframe but it only returns a bunch of NaN or empty. For example:

```
pd.merge(event_logs, machine_event_logs, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='event_log_id')
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank in in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your data schema, you have incompatible types where `id` in *event_logs* is an Integer and `event_log_id` in *machine_event_logs* is a String column. In Python the equality of a string and its equivalent numeric value yields false:

```
print('0'==0)
# False
```

Therefore your pandas left join merge returns all `NAN` on right hand side since no matches are successfully found. Consider converting to align types for proper merging:

```
event_logs['id'] = event_logs['id'].astype(str)
```

OR

```
machine_event_logs['event_log_id'] = machine_event_logs['event_log_id'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you for picking this up. It was unbelievably awesome.